# Why does filtering by 'video' eliminate many actual videos from search results on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The issue I'm seeing is that, in an attempt to filter out channels, when I select the "video" filter (through the YouTube API or a manual search of YouTube) many videos (i.e., not channels) disappear from my search results.

To see what I'm talking about:

1) search YouTube for "Salesforce Lightning|Apex|API"
2) sort by View Count

==> Note that the first video result in the list is one entitled "Hands-on Training: Get Started with Apex Code for Admins" with about 59,000 views. There are also many other videos in the search results with thousands of views.

3) Now filter for Videos only.

==> Note that 69 results (including channels) has been reduced to 218 results. And that the top result is a video with only 402 views.

This doesn't make sense, and seems like a bug to me. But strangely, it seems like--in some cases--a couple hours after I notice issues with some of these atypical (probably not run by the typical YouTube user) queries the results spontaneously correct themselves.

Can anyone provide insight into why this is happening, and what I can do to workaround this behavior? It almost seems like, for atypical queries (for which no results have been cached), YouTube must have to run some aggregation queries or background processes. Which may mean that the initial search fails, and will fail for some unknown time, but then after some number of hours or days the search will succeed. Is this true? Is their a reliable time window I can use? I.e., if I know the time window than I can pass my initial query to prime the pump, and then re-run the query a couple hours (or whatever) later and grab the desired data.

I appreciate your thoughts and assistance!

Comment: Can you please include in your question on how you do it through API? With the request on how you do it.

Comment: ...And now it's fixed magically. Why can't they just make it work correctly up-front? Rather than fixing it when someone like me reports that it's obviously broken, but only fixing the query we report. Is someone literally doing manual work to keep things on the YouTube backend working? It seems like this should be automated and straightforward.